# When is the natural representation of the real/complex group $SO(n)$ on $\Bbb R^n $/$\Bbb C^n $ unitary?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, lie-groups, group-actions

**Is the natural representation of the real group $SO(n)$ on $\Bbb R^n $ unitary?**

I am trying to prove that is it not

My definition of unitary representation: A unitary G representaion of a Lie group $G$ is a continuous representation on a Hilbert space $V$ s.t $\pi(g)$ is a unitary operator for all $g \in G$ (namely $<\pi(g)v,\pi(g)v'>=<v,v'>$)

Take $x,y  \in \Bbb R^n$, the standart inner product $<x,y>=x^T y$.

Let's say I try to prove that $\pi(g):\Bbb R^n  \to \Bbb R^n :v\mapsto gv$ is unitary($g \in SO(n)$):

$<\pi(g)x,\pi(g)y>=<gx,gy>=(gx)^Tgy=x^Tg^Tgy=x^T y=<x,y>$

**Isn't this proving that $\pi(g)$ is unitary, contrary to my expectations?**

---

Edit:

So I am kind of confused seems like unitary means is more than preserving the scalar product.

Using  $SO(n,\Bbb R)$ and $SO(n,\Bbb C)$ to distinguish the real and complex groups. I have the following representaion , I'd like to determine which of them are or are not unitary, preserve or not the scalar product and/or are unitary representations. I'll'do the preserving part at least, and I hope I can get some help saying with determining if the operator can be called unitary:

**i) Representation of $SO(n,\Bbb R)$ on $\Bbb R^n$**

Here the standard scalar product $<x,y>=x^T y$.

As above: here $g \in SO(n,\Bbb R)$, so it's a matrix with real coefficients acting on real vectors

$<\pi(g)x,\pi(g)y>=<gx,gy>=(gx)^Tgy=x^Tg^Tgy=x^T y=<x,y>$ the scalar product is conserved

**ii) Representation of $SO(n,\Bbb C)$ on $\Bbb R^n$**

Here the standard scalar product $<x,y>=x^T y$

$g \in SO(n,\Bbb C)$, so it's a matrix with complex coefficients acting on real vectors, the result will be in general a complex vector so I guess this is not an action anymore, since the codomain has changed

$<\pi(g)x,\pi(g)y>=<gx,gy>=....$ I get complex vectors but my scalar product was defined on $\Bbb R^n$ . I think this makes no sense, or is it a way to make it have sense?

**iii) Representation of $SO(n,\Bbb R)$ on $\Bbb C^n$**

Here the standard scalar product $<x,y>=x^T \bar y$.

$g \in SO(n,\Bbb R)$, so it's a matrix with real coefficients ( $\overline{g}=g$) acting on complex vectors

$<\pi(g)x,\pi(g)y>=<gx,gy>=(gx)^T\overline{gy}=x^Tg^T\overline{gy}=x^Tg^T\bar{g}\bar{y} =x^T \bar y=<x,y>$

The scalar product is preserved

**iv) Representation of $SO(n,\Bbb C)$ on $\Bbb C^n$**

Here the standard scalar product $<x,y>=x^T \bar y$.

$g \in SO(n,\Bbb C)$, so it's a matrix with complex coefficients acting on complex vectors, the result will be in general a complex vector

$<\pi(g)x,\pi(g)y>=<gx,gy>=(gx)^T\overline{gy}=x^Tg^T\bar{g}\bar{y} $

Looks like here the scalar product will not be preserved in general since $g^T\overline{g}\neq I$ in general

Is this OK? Which of these operator are unitary, so that I can talk about a unitary representation?

Comment: I'm not sure what Schur's lemma has to do with this, Schur's lemma talks about intertwining operators between irreducible representations (it's either zero or isomorphism).

Comment: A unitary operator also has to be complex-linear.

Comment: @Ennar, right sorry, I was mixing up things

Comment: @MoisheKohan But in the definition that I was given it is not required, is it?

Comment: On the question of unitarity, operator $U$ is unitary if $UU^* = U^*U = I$, while elements of $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ are orthogonal, that is $O^tO = OO^t = I$. Unitarity supposes that representation is over $\mathbb C$ in the first place.

Comment: @Ennar Yes, so in particular elements of SO(n) are unitary too, arent' them? then the transpose conjugate is just conjugate, so why doesn't this work?

Comment: @Ennar Following my definition, I was taking unitarity to mean just it preserves the scalar product (the namely part)

Comment: Then the answer is yes, since the group of orthogonal matrices is precisely those matrices that preserve (real) inner product (scalar product, if you prefer that term), i.e. $O(n) = \{ A \in M_n(\mathbb R)\mid A^tA = AA^t = I \} = \{ A \in M_n(\mathbb R)\mid \langle Ax,Ay\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle,\ \forall x,y\in\mathbb R^n \}$.

Comment: In general, matrix Lie groups are defined to consist of those matrices that preserve some  bilinear form.

Comment: Then the person who gave you the definition does not know the material they are supposed to teach you.

Comment: @Ennar Could you take a look at my edit and help me clear this up, does it make sense?

Comment: Your work looks correct to me. Whether you want to call representation unitary or not depends how you define it. If your definition only needs preservation of inner product, then 1 and 3 are unitary. If your definition, on the other hand, is that unitary representation is continuous representation on complex Hilbert space, then only 3 is unitary.

Comment: @Ennar Going by the second option,I need $\pi(g)$ to be a unitary operator for every $g \in G$ I found in definition 2 here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator that a unitary operator must also be surjective, how can i check that $\pi(g)$ is surjective in case (iii) ?

Comment: $\pi(g)^{-1} = \pi(g^{-1})$ since it's a group representation.